# Can SASS/Compass compile foo.scss to foo.min.css and foo.dbg.css?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I want to compile a set of `.scss` files to different filenames.

In development, I want to compile eg. `foo.scss` to `foo.dbg.css` (unminified and with comments). In production, I want to have eg. `foo.min.css` (minified).

Is there a way to tell SASS/Compass what to use as the target extension? A command-line switch? A `config.rb` option?

Writing a script that first compiles and then renames files seems like a bad option, because then I can't use `compass watch` efficiently.

(Well, I *could* compile to two different output directories and then write a script that copies the files from there. That feels a bit clumsy.)

**UPDATE:** I worked around the problem by writing a simplified version of the watch code. When something changes, it triggers a recompile to two different output directories, then renames and moves the files to place.

Comment: I'm really interested in your *workaround*! Can you share it to us please?

Comment: Hi @tuomassalo, I'm also interested in the workaround if you have a chance to post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it can't. I asked the same question in the mailing lists about RTL stylesheets.
However, you can run compass compile using different 'config.rb' files.
Try `compass compile -c debug.rb`.

**UPDATE**: Compass still can't, but Gulp can watch and generate several target css files using Sass and Compass. See https://github.com/Snugug/gulp-css-target/

Comment: I don't know if you can run two terminals with `compass watch` on the same project. But if you can, then you got it ;)

Comment: @mtpultz if anyone tries it out and reports a better outcome i'll happily update this answer. logs welcome :)

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't get Alireza Fattahi's answer to work because it threw errors so I found another example which works for me

http://h3r2on.com/2013/05/17/rename-css-on-compile.html

```
require "fileutils"

on_stylesheet_saved do |file|
  if File.exists?(file)
    filename = File.basename(file, File.extname(file))
    File.rename(file, css_dir + "/" + filename + ".min" + File.extname(file))
  end
end
```

Comment: Not work if it is in folder. Example assets/scss/module1/module1.scss should be assets/css/module1/module1.min.css but becomes assets/css/module1.min.css

Answer (score 2):

You can add this to your config.

Please see https://github.com/sbspk/Prepros/issues/38

```
require 'fileutils'

on_stylesheet_saved do |file|

  if file.match('.min') == nil

    require 'compass'

    Compass.add_configuration(
        {
            :project_path => File.dirname(File.dirname(file)),
            :sass_dir => File.basename(File.dirname(file)),
            :css_path => File.basename(File.dirname(file)),
            :output_style => :compressed
        },
        'alwaysmin' # A name for the configuration, can be anything you want
    )
    Compass.compiler.compile(File.dirname(file) + "/" + File.basename(file, '.css') + '.scss', File.dirname(file) + "/" + File.basename(file, '.css') + ".min.css")

  end

end
```