# Can you create two versions of a stylesheet (minified and unminified) using Sass and Compass?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, compass-sass

I use Sass and Compass to create a theme's stylesheet. And in the config.rb file you can set it to compile an expanded (normal) or minified version of the style.css.

Is it possible to set the config.rb up to create both, so you end up with style-min.css and style.css?

Comment: I think this is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404551/can-sass-compass-compile-foo-scss-to-foo-min-css-and-foo-dbg-css, see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In this link you can find the answer to your question.

https://coderwall.com/p/gqqfgw/sass-compass-compile-two-different-files-for-development-and-production-environment-take-2

Comment: Reviewer Comments: Please revise your answer to provide more information/context, not just links to other sites.  Links to other sites often go dead over time and may not be useful to others in the future.